# lombok key already registered

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lombok

I am getting `IllegalArgumentException` key already registered on a custom lombok handler.

```
@ProviderFor(EclipseAnnotationHandler.class)
public class HandleEntityData extends EclipseAnnotationHandler<EntityData> {

@Override
    public void handle(AnnotationValues<EntityData> annotation,
            Annotation ast,
            EclipseNode annotationNode) {

        handleFlagUsage(
             annotationNode, 
             new ConfigurationKey<FlagUsageType>("lombok.entity.flagUsage", 
                    "Emit a warning or error if @EntityData is used.") {}, 
                        "@EntityData"
        ); 


}
```

I already checked that the key is unique.
And so wondering if anyone had ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. Basically moved the CONFIGURATION keys as a separate static constant so that it does not get constructed everytime `handle()` is called. (The identity of the key object seems to fallback to Object equals/hashcode.)

```
@ProviderFor(EclipseAnnotationHandler.class)
public class HandleEntityData extends EclipseAnnotationHandler<EntityData> {

 public final static ConfigurationKey CONFIGURATION_KEY = new ConfigurationKey<FlagUsageType>("lombok.entity.flagUsage", 
                    "Emit a warning or error if @EntityData is used.") {};

@Override
    public void handle(AnnotationValues<EntityData> annotation,
            Annotation ast,
            EclipseNode annotationNode) {

        handleFlagUsage(
             annotationNode, 
             CONFIGURATION_KEYS, 
                        "@EntityData"
        ); 


}
```

Comment: I guess using constants is better anyway. Otherwise, lombok would have to handle things like keys with the same name but different type or description - a needless pain.

Comment: Yes although the key is really a combination of T and the first argument which is `FlagUsageType` and the `"lombok.entity.flagUsage"` so anyone registering a duplicate would be easy to know as well. When the error says "key already used" the first thing anyone would look is to scan if the key is really used by anyone.